# How to find unused CSS rules in a web app?

Tags: html, css, windows

I have 10+ CSS files and around 30+ HTML/JSP files. I want to search each and every class/id in CSS files one by one in all HTML/JSP files so that can remove the rules which are not being used.

Is there any tool available to help in this?

I know there are Chrome/FF plugins to eliminate useless CSS rules but they only work for single page.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [this firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/) and [this plugin for Chrome](http://meeech.amihod.com/very-useful-find-unused-css-rules-with-google)

They appear to do exactly that.

Comment: I think that it's true for the firefox plugin, but the Chrome solution (it's integrated, not a plug-in) I would say that doesn't work for multiple pages (only current one)